# Unalias rename and mv

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

rename, rename.ul (perl one) and mv are essentially different tools of the util-linux package (one of them isn't part of it), that though can do similar tasks (`mv` can rename files, the same as `rename`), they are highly specialized tools.

Please, change this back, there are 169 instances of `rename` (the tool) used that were renamed to [mv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mv) which the [rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rename) tag won't be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine [rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rename) was meant to refer to the action of renaming, not the actual tool, but there's no tag wiki to be sure. I don't know where you came up with 169, but the synonym only took effect 40 times, so the rest of the time people have been choosing [rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rename) to describe their problem. I dropped the synonym for now in case there's actually a need to distinguish usages of `mv` from just generic "renaming files"